# Storing data from mysql

Tags: mysql, c, data-structures, struct

I need an advice from community. I need to store somewhere data from mysql so later I could compare data. I tried to put everything to struct, but I realized that struct was gone after loop, and that i cannot create that struct name would be variable. Like this:

```
struct Columns (variable);
```

So basically I need to store columns information like *field, type, key etc..* I don't know how much there will be tables. 
    My struct:

```
struct Columns {
char  field[1000];
char  type[50];
char  null[10];
char  key[20];
char  defaul[50];
char  extra[50];
};
```

Code part:

```
 if (mysql_query(conn, "Show tables;")){
    fprintf(stderr, "%s\n", mysql_error(conn));
    exit(1);
}
res = mysql_store_result(conn);

printf("MySQL Tables in mysql database:\n");
while ((row = mysql_fetch_row(res)) != NULL){
    printf("%s\n", row[0]);
    sprintf(str, "Show columns from %s;", row[0]); //row[0]-is table names

    sprintf(str1, "lentele_%s", row[0]);
    printf("%s\n", str1);

    struct Columns str1;

    if (mysql_query(conn, str)){
        fprintf(stderr, "%s\n", mysql_error(conn));
        exit(1);
    }

    res2 = mysql_use_result(conn);

    while ((row2 = mysql_fetch_row(res2)) != NULL){

        strcpy(str1.field, row2[0]);

        printf("Belekas Column field %s\n", str1.field);
    }
```

There are 6 columns on each table: **field || type || null || key || default || extra**

As I said, i will need that data for later comparison.

Comment: why you have declared the structure inside the for loop and if you want multiple record to store in the structure then why you are not using structure array ?

Comment: You want to save data, so you will be able to access it later. It doesn't matter where you got the data from, you just need to save it in the correct scope https://www.tutorialspoint.com/cprogramming/c_scope_rules.htm

Comment: To me it sounds as if you need an `array of Columns`. It should probably be dynamic allocated (`malloc`) so that it can grow (`realloc`) if the number of rows in the database exceeds initial size of the array.